# Do pump stacks transmit power vertically in both directions?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

That is to say, if I have 3 pumps stacked properly, and I am suppling excessive power to the middle of the three, will all three run? Or will the top or bottom not receive power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If you've got things correctly stacked, it doesn't matter *where* you connect the power supply, because they're all stacked, and if they're stacked correctly, they are effectively only a single "machine"; Your should be able to <kbd>q</kbd>uery any pump on the stack and get the total power needed (generally 20 x Number of Screw Pumps + inefficiency from gears / axles (5 or 1 per tile, respectively)).